# Add a binding to the source of an image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, binding

I'm trying to retrieve an image from my server to show in my WPF application.
All the images have been named to use the name of the object they represent.

For example: Movie name = Gravity
Link : http://www.somesite.com/something/something/Gravity.jpg

I'm trying to contaminate the default path of the image folder with the binding of the name of the object.

Trying this didn't work (and even gave me errors)

```
<Image Height="100" Width="100" 
       Source="http://www.something.com/something/something/" 
               + {Binding Name} 
               + ".jpg"/>
```

Could you suggest a better way this could be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a converter. `ConverterParameter` is used to specify BaseURI and binding value will contain image name.

```
public class ImagePathConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
         return string.Format("{0}{1}.jpg",parameter, value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then in xaml:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageName, Converter={StaticResource Converter, ConverterParameter='http://www.something.com/something/something/'}}"/>
```

For now I hard coded `.jpg` in converter, you can add it as a parameter if you want it to be a variable.

Comment: +1. Maybe it is also worth to show how the format string could be passed to the converter by the binding's `ConverterParameter` property.

Comment: Might be helpful just in case OP wants to specify the format in XAML. Alternatively it could be a property of the converter that is set when it is instantiated as resource.